# Alpha Not Updating - UIColor

Tags: ios, uicolor

I am trying to change the alpha channel, which was initially set in the `Storyboard` to `0.2`, to `1`:

```
@IBAction func test(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let axOrange = UIColor(red: 0.957, green: 0.635, blue: 0.353, alpha: 1)
    watermarkRows[3].stackView.subviews[20].backgroundColor = axOrange
}
```

I have also tried `UIColor.axOrange.withAlphaComponent(1)` but my GUI does not update.

To note, all of the `UIView` in the `watermarkRows` are loaded from a custom `nib` file.  And, if I change the `backgroundColor` to another color, it does change, but the `alpha` stays the same.

Comment: What happens if you try to change `backgroundColor` to `.blue` or some other color?

Comment: how about changing the `view.alpha` value? because that is a different thing, if you have changed the `alpha` value in IB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alpha component of the `view.backgroundColor` and the `view.alpha` are 2 separate things.

You appear to have set `view.alpha = 0.2` in your storyboard, so to change the alpha in code…

```
@IBAction func test(_ sender: UIButton) {
    watermarkRows[3].stackView.subviews[20].alpha = 1
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked well.  I'll remember that for future reference.